# Problems string from android client to C++ Server

Tags: java, android, c++, client

I am quite new to Android and Java. I need help with an app I'm making.
The app reads a QR code via Intent and sends the information read to a server. I am getting that the port is opened with `nmap -p 3557 192.168.15.18`. When using my app I can't see any information send by it.

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3557/tcp open  unknown


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    //retrieve scan result
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        //we have a result
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
        message = scanContent + " " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())+ " "+ bebidas.getEditableText();
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent + " " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())+ " "+ bebidas.getEditableText());
        DataOutputStream os = null;

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.15.18", 3557);
            os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(message);

            os.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Unkonw exception " + e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException caught " + e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

The codes I am using are from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710093/cant-connect-java-client-to-c-server?rq=1) and it worked for him. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the phone connected to your local network? And have you tried turning off mobile data?

Comment: Yes, it is in the network and the mobile data is turned off.

Comment: So this client does connect? Can you see that on the server?

Comment: You can see it on the server if the server prints `connection made`.

Comment: It seems it doesn't connect.